# Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Precision 5520 freezes intermittently after install and uninstall of i8kutils

Tags: 16.04, dell, fancontrol

I installed i8kutils using apt which installed `acpi` and `tclx8.4`. The fans began to behave strangely the moment the installation ended so I uninstalled i8kutils, acpi and tclx manually.

Now, my computer has frequent millisecond duration freezes every minute. How should I go about solving this?

Thanks.

Comment: `i8kutils` conflicts with `tlp`. `tlp` is a much superior program and I wouldn't recommend using `i8kutils` for fan control unless you have a very old Dell not supported by modern software.

Comment: How do I completely remove `i8kutils` then? Do I have to reinstall `tlp`?

Comment: I posted an answer. Accept it by clicking grey check mark next to it. If you still have problems don't accept the answer and post another comment. BTW I had the same problems with `i8kutils` a few years ago so I know what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by moving to the LTS Enablement stack and to the newest kernel. As far as I understand it, `i8kutils` touched my kernel `4.4.0-143` which made the NVIDIA driver (390.86) fail. It's a documented [bug](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1046451/linux/linux-4-4-168-and-nvidia-linux-x86_64-410-93-and-get_user_pages-/1) and the solution is to move to a newer kernel with the LTSEnablementStack.

Thanks to WinEunuuchs2Unix for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To remove `i8kutils` use:

```
sudo apt remove --purge i8kutils
```

To reinstall `tlp` use:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall tlp
```

Read the associated `tlp` documentation to fine-tune your laptop USB and battery options as needed here:

- https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

### Move to LTS enabled kernel

Upgrading to new kernel solved the problem (as per comments).

Comment: I did this. It doesn't solve the freezing issue.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt autoremove`?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay in response, but yeah I did and I'm still getting intermittent freezes.

Comment: All I can think of is `i8kutils` changed your system BIOS some how. Can you press `F2` whist booting and review all the settings for anything "unusual"?

Comment: What could the unusual setting be exactly? could `i8kutils` have modified the kernel somehow?

Comment: If the kernel was modified you can simply update to a newer version. What does `uname -r` reveal for your current version?

Comment: `uname -r` gives me `4.4.0-142-generic`.

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` should give you version `4.4.0-145-generic`. Then you will have the most current kernel version and any changes `i8kutils` did to `4.4.0-142-generic` will no longer be an issue.

Comment: Moving to a new LTSEnablement kernel helped. The stutters are gone now. Thanks.

Comment: @PVasish I've updated the answer. Kindly click check mark next to it. This way others know the problem is solved. If you prefer post your own answer and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I posted the answer a few minutes ago. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: My pleasure. I upvoted your answer to increase your reputation points, which in turn allows you to do more on this stie :)